# FluentNHibernate exception with a generic base type

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have some classes that implement a generic base type. i.e:

```
public class TreeItem<TEntity> : Entity
where TEntity : TreeItem<TEntity>
{
    public virtual IList<TEntity> Children{get;set;}
    public virtual TEntity Parent {get;set;}
}

public class Category : TreeItem<Category>
{
    public virtual string Description{get;set;}
}

...
```

When using Automapping and building the mappings, FluentNHibernate throws an exception saying "Association references unmapped class". Is using a generic base type incompatible with NHibernate? (I don't map `TreeItem<>` in my mapping).

Comment: Never mind, Looks like `IgnoreBase(typeof(TreeItem<>))` takes care of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IgnoreBase(typeof(TreeItem<>))` Takes care of this.